# no footer/header - extends class?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, fpdf, symfony-plugins

My /symfony/lib/fpdf/fpdf.php:

```
//Version: 1.7                                                                 *

define('FPDF_VERSION','1.7');

class FPDF
{
var $page;               // current page number
var $n; 
....
```

My /symfony/lib/fpdf/extends.php:

```
define('font/');
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {

    //Page header
        function Header() {
            //Logo
            $this->Image('logo_pb.png', 10, 8, 33);
            //Arial bold 15
            $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
            //Move to the right
            $this->Cell(80);
            //Title
            $this->Cell(30, 10, 'Title', 1, 0, 'C');
            //Line break
            $this->Ln(20);
        }

    //Page footer
        function Footer() {
            //Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
            $this->SetY(-15);
            //Arial italic 8
            $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);
            //Page number
            $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page ' . $this->PageNo() . '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
        }

    }
```

My action in some_module/action.class.php:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'cm', 'A4');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);

define('EURO', chr(128));
$pdf->AddPage();
...//somecode what is workking
$pdf->AddPage();
```

But there is no header or footer. What do I do wrong?

Comment: `$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'cm', 'A4');` -> `$pdf = new PDF('P', 'cm', 'A4');` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `PDF` class instead which has been configured.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new class `PDF` which extends the default `FPDF` class. But you instantiate an object (`$pdf`) based on the old class (`FPDF`) instead of the extending class (`PDF`) that contains your header and footer.

So

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'cm', 'A4');
```

should become

```
$pdf = new PDF('P', 'cm', 'A4');
```